# Is there any way not to report re-run failed test case (in extent report) as part of <rerunFailingTestsCount>

Tags: extent

**Environment - Cucumber V. 4.0.0 | Selenium V.3.8.1 | JUnit V.4.12 | Extent Report 3.0/4.0 (anyone)**

Using below Surefire configuration to re-run failed test case. In case, test case gets failed then it would have one more attempt and lets say, test case got passed in 2nd attempt.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-surefire.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <parallel>methods</parallel>
            <threadCount>1</threadCount>
            <reuserForks>false</reuserForks>
            <testErrorIgnore>true</testErrorIgnore>   
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*RunCukeTest.java</include>
            </includes>
            <rerunFailingTestsCount>1</rerunFailingTestsCount>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Once overall build is completed and If I check Cucumber-Maven & Cluecumber Report, then these would have details of only Passed attempt not of 1st attempt in which test case was failed. Which sounds perfect. But,

When i check extent report there i am getting details of both attempts (failed & passed).

[image]

[image]

**Can someone guide me on the below 2 implementations -**

**1.** What thought i shall bring to report only pass test case (in extent report) after launching re-run failed as part of 
(With or without adapter, any one would work), do not want to report failed attempt if test case got passed at nth attempt.

**2.** Sometimes we would need to do analysis why few test cases are getting passed in 2nd/3rd attempt. So is there any way to report failed test in some separate report after launching re-run failed as part of

Any thought would be much appreciated as it would bring innovation in report and we get the best report in terms of failed/passed test case analysis when doing re-run of failed test cases.

Comment: Any thought please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my best knowledge, it was possible using @extendedcucumberoptions in 1.2.5, there one was able to generate a separate report for failed test cases but not possible from 4.0.0 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember, to re-run a test, TestNG initializes execution from scratch which creates a new suite and therefore a brand new report (overrides the existing with new data).

In the current scheme of things, this is not possible but there is an open ticket for this enhancement: github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-java/issues/25